# Consensus and Profile from Rosalind Problems

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I am working on Rosalind problem and specifically problem titled "Consensus and Profile"

The data input is as follows:

```
 >Rosalind_1
 ATCCAGCT
 >Rosalind_2
 GGGCAACT
 >Rosalind_3
 ATGGATCT
 >Rosalind_4
 AAGCAACC
 >Rosalind_5
 TTGGAACT
 >Rosalind_6
 ATGCCATT
 >Rosalind_7
 ATGGCACT
```

The above are seven DNA sequences with their IDs or headers and the output should be something like:

```
ATGCAACT
A: 5 1 0 0 5 5 0 0
C: 0 0 1 4 2 0 6 1
G: 1 1 6 3 0 1 0 0
T: 1 5 0 0 0 1 1 6
```

Now, So far this is my code and I want to generate the matrix above which counts all A's Cs, Gs, and Ts in column-wise:

```
import sys
import Bio.SeqIO

count = {}
count=OrderedDict()
list_seq = [] 
for seq in Bio.SeqIO.parse(sys.stdin, 'fasta'):
    sequn = str(seq.seq)
    print "sequn",sequn
    for i,nuc in enumerate(sequn):
            print "nuc", nuc 
            key = (nuc,i)
            try:
                    count[key] = count[key]+1
            except KeyError:
                    count[key] = 1
```

The output for the dictionary count looks something like this:

```
([(('A', 0), 5), (('T', 1), 5), (('C', 2), 1), (('C', 3), 4), (('A', 4), 5),    
(('G', 5), 1), (('C', 6), 6), (('T', 7), 6), (('G', 0), 1), (('G', 1), 1),   
(('G', 2), 6), (('A', 5), 5), (('G', 3), 3), (('T', 5), 1), (('A', 1), 1), 
(('C', 7), 1), (('T', 0), 1), (('C', 4), 2), (('T', 6), 1)])
```

I want to generate the output matrix from the above output dictionary, how can this be done?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Switching data structures from a dict of tuples to a list of dicts would probably make the problem a lot easier.

Comment: Hey @tripleee I am done with the part for designing the matrix output. But the problem I am having now is how do I get the resulted sequence that is ATGCAACT. It is a result from the most common base in each column. Thats what I am stuck with right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}

count = ([(('A', 0), 5), (('T', 1), 5), (('C', 2), 1), (('C', 3), 4), (('A', 4), 5),(('G', 5), 1), (('C', 6), 6), (('T', 7), 6), (('G', 0), 1), (('G', 1), 1),   
(('G', 2), 6), (('A', 5), 5), (('G', 3), 3), (('T', 5), 1), (('A', 1), 1), 
(('C', 7), 1), (('T', 0), 1), (('C', 4), 2), (('T', 6), 1)])

for each in count:
    if each[0][0] in d:
        li = d[each[0][0]]
        spot = each[0][1]
        li[spot] = each[1]
        d[each[0][0]] = li
    else:       

        li=[0]*8
        spot = each[0][1]
        li[spot] = each[1]
        d[each[0][0]] = li

for each in sorted(d):
    print each," ",d[each]

sol=""
for each in range(8):
    sol+=max(d, key=lambda x:d[x][each])
print sol
```

I just Iterated the whole dict and created a new dict as your question stated.

But you could do that while modifying the dict count. I have assumed the length of list to be 8. If it is above 8. The the above should be modified accordingly.

It would be nice if you could just edit the question to the point.

Comment: Hi @WannaBeCoder, thanks for your reply. I tested the code you wrote and error occurred saying that  spot = each[0][1] IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: I am not getting any such error at spot. Is count what I think it is?

Comment: I fixed the issue it worked thanks a lot but there is one thing I am having trouble with that is how can I output the sequence above the matrix?

Comment: thanks a lot but still the index out range is still there     spot = each[0][1]
IndexError: string index out of range.

Comment: That is very strange I checked my code and I don't get why I am getting the error.

Comment: I think it has something to do with Python Version. I will check it and will let you know meanwhile I truly appreciate your outstanding help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `BioPython` and `collections.Counter`

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from collections import Counter

def main(fasta_file):
    """
    >>> print main(r'./data/CONS_sample.fa')
    ATGCAACT
    A: 5 1 0 0 5 5 0 0
    C: 0 0 1 4 2 0 6 1
    G: 1 1 6 3 0 1 0 0
    T: 1 5 0 0 0 1 1 6
    """
    with open(fasta_file) as fh:
        dna_strings = [str(fasta.seq) for fasta in SeqIO.parse(fh, 'fasta')]
        transposed = zip(*dna_strings)
        counters = [Counter(column) for column in transposed]

        # create consensus
        consensus = ''.join([counter.most_common(1)[0][0] for counter in counters])

        # create profile matrix
        matrix = ''
        for base in 'ACGT':
            matrix += '{}:'.format(base)
            for counter in counters:
                matrix += ' {}'.format(counter[base])
            matrix += '\n'
        matrix = matrix.rstrip()

        return '\n'.join([consensus, matrix])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()

    print main(r'./data/CONS.txt')
```